# jQuery: Can't get .click to work on a div? Newbie?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first time really trying to use jQuery for my personal portfolio and I'm having some problems with it. I want it to have a grid of small images (.piece) that when clicked slides to the left and presents a single large piece (#largeview). Then when you click (#largeview) it should slide away, and show (.piece) again!

See what I'm doing [here](http://ethanbond.com).

The code works up to:

```
 $("#largeview").click(function(){
                                $("#largeview").animate({
                                    opacity: 0,
                                    right: "-1000",
```

So I believe it's the .click that's not catching. Is there any reason for this? This is even with height/width defined in the CSS.

This is the whole block:

```
$(".piece").click(function(){
                $(".piece").animate({
                        opacity: 0,
                        right: "+=1000",
                    }, 1000, function(){
                            $(".piece").hide();
                            $("#largeview").show();
                            $("#largeview").animate({
                                opacity: 1,
                                right: "0",
                            }, 500, function(){
                                $("#largeview .exit").fadeOut("slow");
                                $("#largeview").click(function(){
                                    $("#largeview").animate({
                                        opacity: 0,
                                        right: "-1000",
                                    }, 500, function(){
                                        $("#largeview").hide();
                                        $(".piece").show();
                                        $(".piece").animate({
                                            opacity: 1,
                                            right: "0", 
                                        }, 1000, function(){
                                            //done

                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                    });

            });
```

Thank you to everyone!

Comment: have you added an alert to the click method to see if it does indeed get hit?

Comment: I tried that when I pulled the entire thing into document .ready and it automatically clicked it so it gave an alert on page load.

I just tried it where it is right now and it loops a .click automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `#largeview` is not receiving the click event, it has a `z-index` of `-1` in your CSS on your website. This means that the click event pops up to the its parent and never fires with a target of `#largeview`. If you change the `z-index` to `4` for instance, you'll notice that your page works correctly.

If you have a reason to keep `#largeview` with `z-index: -1` in the CSS, change it when it gets popped in so that it will receive the click event.

**Extra-tip**: To check which element was the target of the click event, I added the following to your javascript and watched the page title as I clicked:

```
$('*').click(function (e) {
    document.title = e.target.tagName + '#' + e.target.id + '.' + e.target.className;
});
```

Comment: Ah! That works beautifully! (I'm new to this whole thing, obviously). Now my next problem is that there seems to be a time between when #largeview comes into view and when you can click on it to make it leave view. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I don't think it is a time between when you can click on it. I think something is causing jQuery to delay that closing animation for a few seconds after you click, try just clicking once and waiting a few seconds. I don't know what is causing that. You may want to change some of your code in the `click()` methods to use `$(this)` to refer to the object clicked rather than reusing your selector to try and target the right object. You'll get yourself confused later on.

Comment: On second thought there is only one place you can change to `$(this)` in your code so far, just remember that for later though.

Comment: Hmm. I'll look into the delay a bit more. It gets really buggy if a user were to try to click in and out of it quickly. The only reason I'm not using $(this) is I want the entire grid to move over. I can use (this) for the #largeview though. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're still having issues with the delay, use the code Honneykeepa posted so that the `click` event is wired up at the start rather once it has finished animating like it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Doe this work for you:

```
$(".piece").click(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    right: "+=1000",
                }, 1000, function(){
                        $(this).hide();
                        $("#largeview").animate({
                            opacity: 1,
                            right: "0",
                        }, 500, function(){
                            $("#largeview .exit").fadeOut("slow");

                        }).show();
                });

        });

        $("#largeview").click(function(){
                                $(this).animate({
                                    opacity: 0,
                                    right: "-1000",
                                }, 500, function(){
                                    $(this).hide();
                                    $(".piece").animate({
                                        opacity: 1,
                                        right: "0", 
                                    }, 1000, function(){
                                        //done

                                    }).show();
                                });
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the CSS. Having removed `z-index: -1` from `#largeview`, I get all clicks captured. Try to either modify `common.css` (which is preferrable) or edit the code by **Sudhir** to (**EDITED** a bit):

```
var $pieces = $('.piece'),
    $largeview = $('#largeview');

$pieces.click(function(){
    $pieces.animate({
            opacity: 0,
            right: '-1000px',
        }, 1000, function() {
            $largeview.show()
                      .animate({
                          opacity: 1,
                          right: '0',
                      }, 500, function() {
                          $largeview.find('.exit').fadeOut('slow');
                      });
    }).hide();
});

$largeview.click(function(){
    $largeview.animate({
                  opacity: 0,
                  right: '1000px'
              }, 500, function(){
                  $pieces.show()
                         .animate({
                             opacity: 1,
                             right: '0'
                         }, 1000);
              })
              .hide();
});
```

Comment: Yep, the z-index was the problem. Now there's a strange delay between the animations though - do you have any idea of how to get rid of that? 

http://ethanbond.com/portfolio.php

Click on a piece, then try to click out of it - it delays for a few seconds. Any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @EthanBond, try to paste the code above. Apart from that, I suppose the lag is caused by the number of `.piece` elements, which are being animated separately. What if you could wrap `.piece` elements into another relatively positioned element and process the animations on it?